# What are OSI model layers! Are they tangible?

Tags: networking, router, switch

I know about all layers and their functions. BUT, how to interfere with/use them? I read that each layer adds its own data, are there 7 layers built into my router/switch ?

Comment: this drives me crazy, I can not find it explained in ANY source or im stupid then!

Comment: it took me quite some time to truly get the meaning of the stack. for now, don't worry about it so much. just know what a switch is for/does, and that its L2. know how tcp works, and worry about it being a transport layer protocol later in life when you have time to mull it over a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are entirely abstract, and just group operations in a way that each set of tasks is modular.

layer 1 just deals with reading electrical/optical signal off the line and making it into digital signal (and vice versa). UTP, stp,  fiber, microwave, rf, etc.

layer 2 just deals with how do two devices talk using a specific layer 1 technology (so how do you cross your lan) Ethernet, Token Ring, Fiberchannel, anything-that-starts--with-802, etc.

layer 3 just deals with how you can connect two or more networks together and can send messages between them. IP, ICMP, IGRP, etc.

layer 4 just deals with how do I tell one connection from another, tell that its intact, in the right order, and all related to the same conversation (TCP/UDP).

Part of your question appears to deal with protocol encapsulation.

L4 segments need to be passed across the internetwork, so they get put L3 packet, which in turn gets put in an L2 frame, and finally is converted into an electrical signal. I know thats a weak description, but you are really better off looking at a diagram.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28networking%29

hope that helps.

Edit: as an attempt to provide a little more context.

First off, on your router. yes, modern routers run on software, and have applications built in so, it is a full stack device, but its probably better not to think of them that way. Networking folks are only concerned with layers 1-4. routing is a layer 3 function, NAT and Firewalls operate at layers 3 and 4, and the management interface operates at layer 7. I think of it as the switch is a layer 2 device, that happens to have a couple layer 3 and 7 functions.

Second, The real purpose of the OSI model, is to allow the reuse and standardization of logic, be that logic written in a circuit, encoded in a rom, or included in a program. a NIC should be able to carry any Layer 3 protocol, or work with most any layer 1 topology (note that this is NOT the case in reality, but in a perfect world...). it allows you to mix and match differant layer implementations, so you could use Cat5e + 802.3 + TCP/IP, or RF + 802.11n + IPX/SPX to build your stack. It allows reuse, because the code or circuirty to build a frame and encapsulate an IP packet into it needs to only be written/printed once and ever layer above can just reuse it as often as they like.

Third, don't worry about layers 5 and 6. they are not of interest to anyone except folks that write operating systems and encoding standards, and they usually don't actually encapsulate any data within the packets. As an application developer and former netadmin I have never ever had to worry about either. I don't even think any common OSs implement them as specified in the OSI. If I need a string to be sent in unicode, I just say so when encoding the string; the host does not encapsulate a PDU header that says "this is utf-8".

so that leaves you with 5 layers to worry about (1-4 and 7).

In terms of how you can interact with the different layers, the lower layers are pretty much set in stone, and shipped to you with your network card, its drivers, and your OSs network stack. you can configure it however to the extent that you can set attributes like the MAC address, IP address, Link speed/duplex, framesize, etc, or by configuring a firewall/nat rule or a static route. you can also daisy chain devices/services. for instance a VPN is essentially a Layer 2 proxy, and TOR is a layer 3 proxy.

The Application layer is where most of the fancy stuff is controlled, but is the domain of developers. they control where to connect to, what to send/request, how to read that data and what to do with it. A developer relies on the lower half of the stack, but it doesn't care a bit about how they are implemented. if I tell a program to make a TCP connection, it doesn't matter what layer 1-3 I have implemented on my network (or any net between source and destination), as long as they function correctly, and support TCP. That is the value of the stack. from any layers perspective, it could care less what the implementation of the lower layers is. the reality is that there is some limitations, because some protocols became powerhouses (802.3 and TCP/IP spring to mind) and layer 1 and 2 implementations are usually tied together of necessity (because they are both implemented partially in the NIC).

so, thats a lot; just hoped to give you some perspective on a matter I had some trouble with when I was getting started. chew it over for a while, and hopefully it will help a little.

good luck

Comment: @Naughty.Coder; I added a good bit to more specifically address your question. Cheers!

Comment: Also, don't worry so much about protocol encapsulation. when you create a packet, you nest each layers PDU inside the lower **if the stack uses one** so most of the time, your packets will consist of headers for layer 2, 3, and 4. your applications data will be in the data region of the segment.

Answer (score 1):

*Are they tangible?*

In a way. Frank Thomas' explanation above is quite good,but let me add one thing. Of course all modern PCs are built to make their users oblivious to the difficulties of the TCP/IP stack, so that not only their routers but also their pcs contain seven layers, without anyone noticing.  Yet you do come into close contact with them on least a couple of occasions.

The first one is in switching. The simple switch you have at home forwards traffic correctly, but it is not a router. What is the difference? The switch is a Layer 2 object, it uses a different protocol (ARP) to forward to a MAC address. The router instead sends packet on to the net hop, on the basis of their IP address, a Layer 3 concept based on a different protocol (IP). As a matter of fact, we all know you cannot substitute one for the other, and this is the reason.

The second one is when you set up a tun/tap connection, and are offered the possibility to choose between a bridged and a routed configuration. This occurs with certain VPNs (OpenVPN is a good case in point), or with Virtual Machines inside a hypervisor (the NAT connection is the routing connection here). These connections are fundamentally different, a bridge working at the Layer 2 level, and a tunnel at the Layer 3 level. Bridging works to `join` two separate networks as if they were one, while routing connects them, while keeping them distinct. This means all the applications which rely on working on a single subnet (samba anyone?) will not work out of the box  with a routed solution, which may be a hindrance (Samba,like I said) or a plus (for instance, with a routed solution you do not waste precious bandwidth to send ICMP packets from one subnet to the other).